# Need help creating a Regex that will match certain c# strings that contain json

Tags: c#, regex, json

I have a bunch of Json style strings in C#, and I'm trying to take the raw string that's actually in the CS file and convert it to a string.format to help parameterize a web request.

So far I have not been able to come up with something that works.

I need a single regex that will match both of these strings:

```
    "{\"effectiveTimestamp\":null
```

`\"foo\":1029231}");`

My regex looks like the following

`\s*\"?{?(.*?):(.*)(?:}\"\);)?`

I've tried different variations of greed and non greedy for the last 2 capture groups.

`\s*\"?{?(.*?):(.*)(?:}\"\);)*`

`\s*\"?{?(.*?):(.*)(?:}\"\);)*?`

`\s*\"?{?(.*?):(.*?)(?:}\"\);)*`

`\s*\"?{?(.*?):(.*?)(?:}\"\);)*?`

As well as trying to match 0 or 1 times

`\s*\"?{?(.*?):(.*)(?:}\"\);)?`

But no matter what I do it either fails to grab the second group in the first string or the second string. I can't get it to grab the 2nd group correctly in both cases.

Got the answer from Matt:

This captures what I needed.

`([\w\\"]*):([\w\\"]+)`

Comment: Compiling and using reflection to grab string may be much easier/readable/safer :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [this](http://regexr.com?324kf)?

```
(\w+)\\?\"\s*\:\s*(\w+)
```

It's hard to tell what you want here, can you give us an example of what groups you're expecting to see in the match?

Comment: Actually your code works fine for what I want, I needed to change the capture groups around to capture the `\"` as well, but what you created works. Thanks.